# jqgrid + tinymce

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce, javascript

Одно из полей редактируемой строки таблицы надо иметь возможность редактировать в редакторе tinymce. Как подружить jqgrid и tinymce - не могу разобраться. Может кто сталкивался, ааа..?

Update:
Вот мой ответ на мой вопрос. (засунул, как вы сказали, в модальное окно) Извините за такое форматирование, не могу разобраться как красиво все оформить :( :
jQuery('#table').jqGrid({

// настройки jqgrid

}).navGrid('#tablePager',

```
    {refresh:true,add:true,edit:true,del:true,search:true},
```

{

// edit parameters

width: "100%",

height: 550,

reloadAfterSubmit:true,

**after**ShowForm: function() {

// перед показом окошка с редактированием, подменяем нужное поле content на редактор

tinyMCE.init({

```
 mode: "exact",

 theme : "advanced",

 language: "ru",

 elements: "content",

 // еще какие-то настройки
```

});

},

onclickSubmit: function() {

var contenttext = tinyMCE.get('content').getContent();

return {

```
 content: contenttext
```

};

},

onClose: function() {

tinyMCE.get('content').remove();

return true;

},

},

{

// add parameters

width: "100%",

height: 550,

reloadAfterSubmit:true,

**before**ShowForm: function() {

```
tinyMCE.init({

 mode: "exact",

 theme : "advanced",

 language: "ru",

 elements: "content",

 height: 400,

 // еще какие-то настройки
```

});

},

onclickSubmit: function() {

var contenttext = tinyMCE.get('content').getContent();

return {

```
content: contenttext
```

};

},

onClose: function() {

tinyMCE.get('content').remove();

},

```
    },

    {

        //delete parameters

    }

);
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Для начала надо решить, где вы собираетесь редактировать это поле. Для jqgrid есть несколько вариантов.

1. inline, когда редактирование идет в строке.
2. в диалоге самого jqgrid'а (метод `editGridRow`. см примеры [Live data manipulation](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html))
3. или самостоятельно, в своих элементах изменяя данные программно

Короче говоря, надо понять, какой элемент у вас будет TinyMCE.

Для первого варианта подойдет метод, который реализован с интеграцией datepicker'а. (см. в примерах Integration->Datepicker. Т.е. создается отдельный div, который показывается при inline-редактировании).

Во втором случае просто надо применить к соответствующему элементу textarea функцию tinymce (см [TinyMCE jQuery plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/jquery_plugin.php)).

В третьем случае - понятно, - для своего элемента добавить функционал tinymce...

Answer (score 2):

Хороший вопрос.
Например, можно разместить `tinymce` в скрытом `div'е`, по нажатию на нужную ячейку (кнопку в ячейке) передавать необходимое поле в `tinymce` и отображать его. После операций над текстом аяксом апдейтить данные, скрывать поле и обновлять таблицу `jqgrid` (насколько я помню там есть специальный метод для этого).

UPDATE. Для отображения `tinymce` можно засунуть в модальное окно. Например, в [JQueryUI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal). Так будет красивее :)

Answer (score 2):

Может я не так понял, но на всяк случай. Для динамической подгрузки в поле и сохранения у них предусмотрены две функции. Код из их примеров:

```
function ajaxLoad() {
        var ed = tinyMCE.get('content');

        // Do you ajax call here, window.setTimeout fakes ajax call
        ed.setProgressState(1); // Show progress
        window.setTimeout(function() {
                ed.setProgressState(0); // Hide progress
                ed.setContent('HTML content that got passed from server.');
        }, 3000);
}

function ajaxSave() {
        var ed = tinyMCE.get('content');

        // Do you ajax call here, window.setTimeout fakes ajax call
        ed.setProgressState(1); // Show progress
        window.setTimeout(function() {
                ed.setProgressState(0); // Hide progress
                alert(ed.getContent());
        }, 3000);
}
```

P.S. Если с английскким дружите, то можно задать вопрос прямо ним или на их форуме. Думаю, что эта аналогичная тема там поднималась.

Comment: Спасибо за попытку помочь, но это не то.